# android I/O Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: android

> error :I/O Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

I tried killing and resetting ADB but no resolution.(Error happened in Samsung galaxy S5).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally Fixed : I had to update Android SDK **[image: update the SDK]**.....

Comment: what do you mean you had to update Android SDK, can you provide a bit more to that answer?